# How to check if current view already has a scene presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, sprite-kit

I'm trying to understand how i could guard the view controller from presenting the same scene over and over again when a new scene/subview is added. In viewWillLayoutSubviews, I read a post saying that I should use `if(self.view.scene == nil){//present view}`. However, I'm getting an error saying that Property scene is not an object of the type uiview

Comment: Try casting it as (SKView*) or (SKScene*) pending on how you want to write it before you do a null check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done it is create a static reference.

```
static SKScene *scene = nil;
if (!scene) {
    //create and present
}
```